Intellij Idea with Gradle does not show errors message
I've found this posting and tried as described in the comment, but nothing works. I'm using  IntelliJ Idea 2024.1.4 ( Ultimate ) with Gradle Java project.
If there is an error when run a problem, I only see the following message.

build.gradle is
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.0.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:5.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

//
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainClass = 'learn_java.qualifier_annotation.CoffeeApp'
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ['-ea']
    if (project.hasProperty('debug')) {
        jvmArgs += ['-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005']
    }
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
    standardInput = System.in
    standardOutput = System.out
    errorOutput = System.err
}


